# How to make a local type in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a type in Clojure only visible from the current namespace.

Having a type `my-type` defined in `my.ns`

```
(ns my.ns)

(deftype my-type
  Protocol
  (some-function[]))
```

How to avoid the usual import strategy, making the type private?

```
(ns other.ns
  (:import my.ns.my-type)

(->my-type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent your types from being imported, since they are just public classes. You can make the factory functions private like so:

```
(deftype Foo [])

(alter-meta! #'->Foo assoc :private true)
```

For a completely hidden "type", you could use `reify` in a private factory function:

```
(defn ^:private make-foo [& args]
  (reify SomeProtocol
    (method1 [this] ...)))
```

One potential problem here is that you will not be able to use `extend-type` and similar to augment such a "type".

Protocols, on the other hand, can be made private, with the caveat that their accompanying interfaces will still be public:

```
(defprotocol ^:private PFoo
  (^:private foo [this]))
```

`:private` metadata is needed on both the protocol Var and the individual methods, since they receive their own separate Vars. With the above in place, the interface `some.ns.PFoo` will still be public, but the protocol `some.ns/PFoo` will not.

Comment: Agreed about Protocols, but are different uses cases. Types are similar to Records, since both of them can implement Protocols. I wan't to avoid someone external from (ab)using the local defined Type, it's not an interface thing IMO.